# change ordering mode of std::map

Tags: c++, stl, stdmap

I am creating a `std::map<a,b>` where the ordering criteria is defined with `a::operator<`.

Is there any way at some point to change the type of the map so that it gets from now on ordered by another sorting algorithm on `a`? It would need to re-order the current content of the map too.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the ordering of `std::map<a,b>` is defined by `std::less<a>`.

Comment: @Robᵩ, and if you haven't specialized `std::less<a>` it will call `a::operator<` so you're both right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would have to create another map, and copy the elements of the first map into the second, like so:

```
std::map<a,b> map1;
... // operations on map1
std::map<a,b,Sorter> map2(map1.begin(), map1.end());
```

Comment: Then I guess I can't swap map1 for map2 since they have different types? It's ok for me, just wondering out of curiosity...

Comment: @lezebulon, right you can't swap them. The internal data representation depends on the comparison function, so even if the declarations allowed it wouldn't be practical.

Answer (score 1):

The answer lies in the declaration of `std::map`

```
template < class Key, class T, class Compare = less<Key>,
           class Allocator = allocator<pair<const Key,T> > > class map;
```

The `Compare` template argument can be used to define comparison for the ordering of the map:

> **Compare**: Comparison class: A class that takes two arguments of the key
>   type and returns a bool. The expression comp(a,b), where comp is an
>   object of this comparison class and a and b are key values, shall
>   return true if a is to be placed at an earlier position than b in a
>   strict weak ordering operation. This can either be a class
>   implementing a function call operator or a pointer to a function (see
>   constructor for an example). This defaults to less, which returns
>   the same as applying the less-than operator (a < b). The map object uses
>   this expression to determine the position of the elements in the
>   container. All elements in a map container are ordered following this
>   rule at all times.

I quoted this from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/)

Comment: That doesn't directly answer the question.  I could pass in a stateful class implementing `operator()()`, where the behavior depends on other members of the functor object and still comply with everything you mentioned.  Now, actually changing data that influenced the ordering after `operator()()` has been called at least once would violate the strict weak ordering requirements.  But that's very unclear from your answer.

Comment: @BenVoigt I don't think I get what you're saying. OP asked how he can apply a new ordering to his map.  To apply another ordering you can use the `Compare` template argument.  I don't see the issue???

Comment: BTW, [quoting from `cplusplus.com` is a bad idea.](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/88241/whats-wrong-with-cplusplus-com)

Comment: You can't change template arguments of an object, it's part of the compile-time type and baked in.